# Constract a compact set of real numbers whose limit points form a countable set.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

This is exercise $2.13$ in Rudin.

Can't we simply define such set as $[a, b]$, with all members being rational? It is bounded, and closed (proof is straightforward), and the limit points are all members of the set since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense on an interval; and since rational numbers are countable then all the limit points are. Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: in this case set of limits points is actually [a,b]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want limit points should be finite then {1/n| n $\in \mathbb{N} $}$\cup$ {0} in case of 
limit points countably infinite:- for each n$\in \mathbb{N}$ define $M_n$ = { 1/n +1/r | r$\in \mathbb{N}$ and 1/r < 1/(n-1) - 1/(n)} $\cup$ {1/n}, define $ M = \bigcup_{n>1} M_n$.
claim: the required set is $M \cup {0}$... this set is compact since closed and bounded and set of limits points are {1/n| n $\in \mathbb{N} $}$\cup$ {0} which is countable

Comment: here actually I've constructed a set only using rationals

Answer (score 1):

You have stated why this doesn't work. The limit points comprise the entire interval $[a,b]$, which is not a countable set.

Comment: But the interval contains only rational numbers, and even if their number is infinite in this interval, they are countable (as $Q$ is).

Comment: "limit points" of a set can include things not in the set.  Besides, your set is not compact, either.

Comment: Presumably, we are working in the reals, not the rationals. In the rationals, every subset is countable. You should be looking for this set to be closed and bounded in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Got it, sorry, silly question. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Would the set of 1/n (n integers) and 0 do? In that case, 0 is the only limit point.

Comment: Technically, yes, as would any convergent sequence together with its limit. However, I suspect the question intends there to actually be a countably *infinite* set of limit points. But that's easy, right? Just take the countable compact set you constructed, and for each point in that set, throw in a sequence converging to that point. So, I think $$\{\tfrac1k + \tfrac1n:k,n\in\mathbb N\}\cup\{0\}$$ would work.

Comment: (addendum) You may want to ensure that the sequences don't overlap, to avoid introducing possible additional limit points; so perhaps adding the restriction that $n>k$ is a good idea.